# How to sort DDL by name of the object

Tags: sorting, awk, file-processing

I want to sort the generated DDL of a database by name of the object. For example, I have the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable3 (
  col1 integer,
  col2 varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE MyTable1 (
  col1 integer
);

CREATE TABLE MyTable2 (
  col1 integer,
  col2 varchar(10),
  time timestamp
  time2 timestamp
);
```

And I want the following output:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable1 (
  col1 integer
);

CREATE TABLE MyTable2 (
  col1 integer,
  col2 varchar(10),
  time timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE MyTable3 (
  col1 integer,
  col2 varchar(10)
);
```

I have tried with awk, but I do not know to specify multiple lines: awk -F; '{print $NB}'

I found that [msort](http://billposer.org/Software/msort.html) could be the solution, but this package is not longer maintained.

As you can see, each element can have different quantity of lines, and I want to sort them by the first line which contains the name of the object.

What other options do I have to sort a document by multiple lines and a specific terminator (semi-colon).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below gawk solution. The solution however assumes the tablename is in the same line as CREATE TABLE.

```
awk '
BEGIN {
}
{
        if($0 ~  /CREATE TABLE/) {
                found = match($0, /CREATE TABLE (.*) \(/, ary);
                if(found != 0)
                {
                        tablename=ary[1];
                }
                oneDDL=$0;
        }
        else if($0 ~  /;/) {
                oneDDL=oneDDL"\n"$0;
                arr[tablename]=oneDDL;
        }
        else {
                oneDDL=oneDDL"\n"$0;
        }
}
END {
        asort(arr);
        for(i in arr) {
                print arr[i];
                print "\n";
        }
}' Input_File
```

Put `tablename` in an array `arr` as index with value as the text of DDL `oneDDL`.

Sort the array.
Then print the contents of the array.